# Upgrade jQuery plugins to latest version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have quick question about jQuery plugins, hope somebody out there has some advice. 
I'm working with a jQuery plugin that has been working as expected, but in the last couple of days we upgraded from jQuery 1.1.4 to 1.4.2.
After a lot of debugging, I was able to realize that in the old plugin, selectors are written as follows:

```
 $('img[@id&=myImage]').each ...
```

Once we upgraded to the latest version of jQuery, I started getting JavaScript errors as follows:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@id&=myImage]
```

As you can see, the selector includes an "@" symbol (which I believe is the one causing the error) and after consulting the jQuery documentation about all the different type of selectors, I was not able to find whether this was correct or not, given that it worked before and now it doesn't.

At this point I have to figure out if I can use the old plugin with the new version of jQuery or if I have to come up with an alternative solution.

I'd appreciate any advice.
Thanks

Comment: Simply removing the `@` should do it. But the `&` in your expression, are you sure that's the code? It's not `^=` or `~=` or `$=` ?

Comment: See the current attribute selector documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Yes, it is an ampersand, and yes based on the documentation it should not be there, but it worked before so I did not question it.
I removed all the instances of the "@" symbol and I don't get error but the plugin does not work at all.

Comment: Maybe a hint as to what the plugin does might help to uncover what the ampersand was meant to be about.

Comment: That is the problem, I know what it does but I don't know how it does it.  This is a plugin that creates a help balloon, tooltip like speech bubble for links, to offer more info on any given links.
I can't explain it very well because I really don't understand it very well myself.
I'll continue trying to figure this one out.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` for [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) was [removed in jQuery 1.3](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3#Upgrading), just take it out, like this:

```
$('img[id^=myImage]').each(...);
```

Also I'm not sure what `&=` would have referred to, I think you want one of the other [attribute selectors here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), possibly [starts-with (`^=`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) or [ends-with (`$=`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)?

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was not sure about, I removed the "@" from every selector, but that causes the plugin to stop working all together.

Comment: @jnkrois - What is the markup you're running against? It would be `#myImage` if it was *just* the ID, but it must have intended a starts with, ends with, contains, etc...if you posted the element markup, it would be easier to tell.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I really would not like to post some of the code, because I don't understand it very well myself, so I won't waste your time, but I do appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: @jnkrois - What does the `<img />` tag look like? the `id="something"` is what this is after..does it start with "myImage", end with it, contain it?

Comment: thanks Nick, the "^" fixed my problem and I removed the "&" also because it was not doing anything for the selector either.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It all boils down to the pros and cons of upgrading. 
Pros for upgrading are :

1. The newer version definitely has a lot of improvements in terms of
   speed/performance and also bug fixes.
2. New plugins of jQuery would probably require the new version and in the long term you might benefit from these .

Cons :

1. You need to take care of all the plugins that break in the new
   version . Like the one in question (
   I guess you could just take out the
   @ symbol and it should work ) .
2. How many such plugin you are using and what is the current size of your
   js code that can break with this
   upgrade. The jQuery release
   documentations like [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2.6) and
   [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3)  might be a starting point

You could take a decision based on the cost and time estimate of the above. If there are just 1 or 2 plugins that needs a little tweaking, I would say definitely go ahead and upgrade . 
However if you have a dozen plugin that break and you would have to rewrite almost 50 - 60% of your frontend code again, then you have a tough call to make :)